# redirect to current page in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

How can I perform a redirect with `Server.Transfer()` to the same page that is currently shown?

I want to have A cleared form after submit.

What other/better methods can I use to achieve the same?

Comment: If you only want cleared form after submit, then just clear all your field values in ur code at last, rather then rediret to same page

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Why `Server.Transfer`? `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)` would get you what you need.

Comment: I think that Server.Transfer is the better option. But your solution does the trick too. I'm using now Server.Transfer(Request.Path);

Comment: @Daniel: It's not a wasted round trip.  Quite often you don't want the last request in your user's browsers page stack to be the result of an HTTP POST.  Users will often refresh and repeat that action.  Transfer doesn't fix that, but Redirect does.

Comment: @Daniel: Exactly, ever heard of Post-Redirect-Get pattern? If not here is some info for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 18):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

The most common way to implement this pattern in ASP.Net is to use *Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)*

Consider the [differences between Redirect and Transfer](http://www.developer.com/article.php/3299641).  Transfer really isn't telling the browser to *forward to a clear form*, it's simply returning a cleared form.  That may or may not be what you want.

*Response.Redirect()* does not a waste round trip.  If you post to a script that clears the form by *Server.Transfer()* and reload you will be asked to repost by most browsers since the last action was a HTTP POST.  This may cause your users to unintentionally repeat some action, eg. place a second order which will have to be voided later.